# Подсчёт количества строк в таблице по условию — SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

У меня есть таблица `groupsData` со столбцами `_id`, `group_id`, `question` и `answer`. В качестве примера приведу один из вариантов заполнения таблицы:
[image: Пример таблицы groupsData]
Так же есть таблица `groupInfo` со столбцами `_id`, `name` и `text`.
[image: Пример таблицы groupsInfo]
В приложении это будет выглядеть подобным образом:
[image: Пример в приложении]
В последней строчке выводится количество карточек в наборе. Я беру `_id` строчки в таблице `groupsInfo` и хочу получить количество строк с `group_id` равным ранее взятому `_id`. Как мне это сделать?

Я попробовал сделать вот так:

```
ArrayList<GroupModel> groups = new ArrayList<GroupModel>();

SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursorInfo = db.query("groupsInfo", null, null, null, null, null, null);

while (cursorInfo.moveToNext()) {

    String groupName = cursorInfo.getString(cursorInfo.getColumnIndex("name"));
    String groupText = cursorInfo.getString(cursorInfo.getColumnIndex("text"));
    int groupCardsIn = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "groupsData", "group_id = ?", new String[]{ String.valueOf(cursorInfo.getColumnIndex("_id")) });

    groups.add(new GroupModel(groupName, groupText, groupCardsIn));
}

cursorInfo.close();
db.close();
```

Но независимо от количества количества карточек в БД во всех полях выводится количество карточек в первом наборе. Из за чего это?

Comment: Например, так: `long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, table, "group_id = ?", new String[]{ String.valueOf(group_id) })`

Comment: @woesss что такое `queryNumEntries`? У меня среда разработки выдаёт `Unknown method 'queryNumEntries' of android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase`

Comment: @woesss приложение почему-то даёт сбой

Comment: В чём это выражается?

Comment: @woesss просто вылетает при запуске

Comment: Во-первых: смотрите в `LogCat` - просто так ничего не вылетает, даже мухи. Во-вторых:  этот код должен выполняться там, где у Вас база уже открыта и ещё не закрыта.

Comment: @woesss извиняюсь, это я напортачил. Просто опечатка в названии таблицы.